# Struts2 setter method for POST parameter with dash

Tags: java, struts2, mailgun

I have mailgun.com routes to forward email POST to my Struts2 Action. The mailgun POST request content dashes in some parameter names: **sender**, **subject** (OK) but how can I map setter method in my Struts2 Action for POST parameter: **`body-plain`** (contain dash), `body-html`, `message-headers`, `Content-Type` ?

I have try this but not work `bodyPlain=null`:

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String sender;
    private String subject;
    private String bodyPlain;

    public String execute() {

        LOG.info(sender);
        LOG.info(subject);
        LOG.info(bodyPlain);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public void setBodyPlain(String bodyPlain) {
        this.bodyPlain = bodyPlain;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you make  a post request and how did you pass parameters, on the struts side the `struts.xml` is required to handle the request.

Comment: Yes I have in struts.xml namespace defined for this action. Its work I have sender and subject property in setters mapped correctly only body-plain parameter is not set. This is Struts2 Mapping issue.

Comment: The easiest might be an interceptor that maps them to standard Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you need to rename `body-plain` to **`bodyPlain`** to map parameters to the action fields. Java and naming conventions use *camelCased* instance variables for classes. And this is an obligatory rule to map request parameters to the action class.

You can translate/rename them on any level, filter, url-rewrite rule, interceptor, etc. Any way parameters are passed to the `ActionContext` that is a map, then traversing the map and remove dashes from the key names would be easy if you try

```
Map<String, Object[]> parameters =  ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
```

Comment: I cant rename body-plain POST parameter. It is send from mailgun email service.

Comment: I would suggest you to modify this service if possible or if you can't do this you can try any other method listed in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can`t change [mailgun](http://mailgun.com) service code. This is my code to deal with Struts2 naming conventions. If its have more clean solution for this problem let me know.

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements ParameterAware {

        private String sender;
        private String subject;
        private String bodyPlain;

        public String execute() {
            LOG.info(sender);
            LOG.info(subject);
            LOG.info(bodyPlain);
            return SUCCESS;
        }

        public void setSender(String sender) {
            this.sender = sender;
        }

        public void setSubject(String subject) {
            this.subject = subject;
        }

        @Override
        public void setParameters(Map<String, String[]> parameters) {
            if (parameters != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    String[] value = entry.getValue();
                    if(key.equals("body-plain") && value.length > 0) this.bodyPlain = value[0];
                    LOG.info("key:" + key + " value:" + Arrays.toString(value));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```